# Command line arguments in 64 bit os

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit

I have code that worked fine on 32 bit Excel.
The code doesn't work on 64 bit excel.
No error is given when I copy paste declarations in 64 bit Excel.
The declarations are in RED and are not recognized.

The code is used to retrieve command line arguments.

So for example, If I ran:
start Excel "C:\GD\Edu Recent\ParametersProject.xlsm" /p/"kjh%dg.pdf"
it would return string that I could parse and determine the input parameters:
"C:\GD\Edu Recent\ParametersProject.xlsm" /p/"kjh%dg.pdf"

How would I make the shift?

Here is the code:

```
'I declared this code in a module called Parameters:

Declare Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)


Public Function CmdLineToStr() As String

'
' Returns the command line in the call to Excel
'
Dim Buffer() As Byte
Dim StrLen As Long
Dim CmdPtr As Long

CmdPtr = Parameters.GetCommandLine()
If CmdPtr > 0 Then
  StrLen = lstrlenW(CmdPtr) * 2
  If StrLen > 0 Then
    ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
    CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal CmdPtr, StrLen
    CmdLineToStr = Buffer
  End If
End If

End Function
```

And...

```
'I declared this code in the Workbook open:

Sub workBook_open()
    MsgBox Parameters.CmdLineToStr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare statements with the PtrSafe keyword is the recommended syntax. In 64-bit Declare statement example:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "User32" () As LongPtr
```

Check this documentation for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declare-statement